# Submitting Pardot Form Handler to Pardot as well as own server

Tags: forms, pardot

We are looking to send a form to Pardot as a prospect and then send them to our database as well. When I tried the hidden iframe trick I got a network error (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED).

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313655&type=1&mode=1

I followed the suggestions on that page and it is failing to submit.

```
<?php
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
echo '<iframe src="https://mypardot.url.com/l/123/2009-04-28/ABCDE?first_name='.$first_name.'&last_name='.$last_name.'&email='.$email.'&phone='.$phone.'" width="1" height="1"></iframe>';
?>
```

I get the correct URL back and it looks right.

Answer (score 0):

You could just post the data from your PHP script directly to your own database (prior to the iframe rendering).

Hate to be that guy...I am assuming the sample you provided is a shortened sample VS the code you actually have in use. Sanitation and validation will be pretty important!